# Running boot2docker within a Windows 7 64Bit Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, vt-x, docker

For a project my team is trying to set up a test/development environment including programs and services like different database-system as well as docker.
To guarantee a working environment, we have set up a virtual machine, where we have installed the programs.

Now we stuck at the problem that docker is not able to start the boot2docker-VM, because of a missing VTX support (hardware virtualization technology).
In the end my final question is: Is it possible to run the boot2docker-VM within a Windows guest VM? From my understanding, I have to emulate VT-X within the guest-system to enable a proper working docker-VM.

Some information about the environment:
**Host-System:**
OS: Windows 7 64bit Enterprise
CPU: [Intel Core i3 3220](http://ark.intel.com/products/65693/Intel-Core-i3-3220-Processor-3M-Cache-3_30-GHz), which supports VT-X. Otherwise I would not be able to run the Guest-System, which is a x64 system, would I?
RAM: 8GB
VM-Software: Oracle Virtual Box

**Guest-System and VirtualBox Settings:**
OS: Windows 7 64Bit Professional
Settings: 3GB RAM, 2 Cores, VT-x/AMD-V and Nested Paging is enabled

Any tips and hints are much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if the virtualization is disabled in your BIOS?

Comment: Jepp. I've checked it and it's is enabled. Also the Guest System (Win 7 Pro 64Bit) runs without any problems and as far as I know, this would not be possible without an enabled virtualization-mode, would it?